# Back Propagation Derivation - where am I going wrong

Tags: neural-networks, python, backpropagation, matrix-calculus

This is a rather long question. Sorry for that. The main thing is that I tried to derive out backpropagation via chain rule etc. I am aware that the index notation changes to transpose the matrix while doing multiplication; and also that for matrix calculus Hadamard product is needed. However, I am not exactly clear where each has to apply. I derived out the equation of the last layer and inner layers with index notation. I tried to implement a simple CNN to test this out; however, during backpropagation, the weights are not matching. Even when I try to do Hadamard product (element-wise multiplication). Not able to break through.

Excerpt from     https://alexcpn.github.io/html/NN/ml/7_backpropogation_full/

---

Neural Network

$$
\mathbf {
\bbox[10px, border:2px solid red] { \color{red}{
\begin{aligned}
 a^0 \rightarrow
    \bbox[5px, border:2px solid black]  {
      \underbrace{\text{hidden layers}}_{a^{l-2}} }
      \,\rightarrow
    \bbox[5px, border:2px solid black]  {  
      \underbrace{w^{l-1} a^{l-2}+b^{l-1}}_{z^{l-1} }
    }
      \,\rightarrow
    \bbox[5px, border:2px solid black]  {  
      \underbrace{\sigma(z^{l-1})}_{a^{l-1}}
    }
    \,\rightarrow
    \bbox[5px, border:2px solid black]  {  
     \underbrace{w^l a^{l-1}+b^l}_{z^{l}/logits }
    }
    \,\rightarrow
    \bbox[5px, border:2px solid black]  {  
    \underbrace{P(z^l)}_{\vec P/ \text{softmax} /a^{l}}
    }
    \,\rightarrow
  \bbox[5px, border:2px solid black]  {  
    \underbrace{L ( \vec P, \vec Y)}_{\text{CrossEntropyLoss}}
  }
\end{aligned}
}}}
$$

---

#### CrossEntropy Loss with respect to Weight in last layer

$$
\mathbf {
\frac {\partial L}{\partial w^l} 
=  \color{red}{\frac {\partial L}{\partial z^l}}.\color{green}{\frac {\partial z^l}{\partial w^l}} \rightarrow \quad EqA1
}
$$
$$ \color{red}
  {
  \begin{aligned}
     \frac {\partial L}{\partial z^l}  = p_i - y_i \rightarrow \quad \text{EqA1.1}
\end{aligned}
}
$$
We need to put this back in $EqA1$. We now need to calculate the second term, to complete the equation

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac {\partial L}{\partial w^l} 
=  \color{red}{\frac {\partial L}{\partial z^l}}.\color{green}{\frac {\partial z^l}{\partial w^l}}
\\ \\
z^{l} = (w^l a^{l-1}+b^l) 
\\
 \color{green}{\frac {\partial z^l}{\partial w^l} = a^{l-1}}
 \\ \\ \text{Putting all together} \\ \\
 \frac {\partial L}{\partial w^l} = (p_i - y_i) *a^{l-1} \quad  \rightarrow \quad \mathbf  {EqA1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Using Gradient descent we can keep adjusting the last layer like

$$
     w{^l}{_i} = w{^l}{_i} -\alpha *  \frac {\partial L}{\partial w^l} 
$$

Now let's do the derivation for the inner layers

### Derivative of Loss with respect to Weight in Inner Layers

he trick here (yes it is a trick), is to derivative the Loss with respect to the inner layer as a composition of the partial derivative we computed earlier. And also to compose each partial derivative as partial derivative with respect to either $z^x$ or $w^x$ but not with respect to $a^x$. This is to make derivatives easier and intuitive to compute.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac {\partial L}{\partial w^{l-1}} 
=  \color{blue}{\frac {\partial L}{\partial z^{l-1}}}.
     \color{green}{\frac {\partial z^{l-1}}{\partial w^{l-1}}} \rightarrow \text{EqA2}
\end{aligned}
$$

The trick is to represent the first  part  in terms of what we computed earlier; in terms of $\color{blue}{\frac {\partial L}{\partial z^{l}}}$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\color{blue}{\frac {\partial L}{\partial z^{l-1}}} =
\color{blue}{\frac {\partial L}{\partial z^{l}}}.
    \frac {\partial z^{l}}{\partial a^{l-1}}.
    \frac {\partial a^{l-1}}{\partial z^{l-1}} \rightarrow \text{ Eq with respect to Prev Layer}
  \\ \\
  \color{blue}{\frac {\partial L}{\partial z^{l}}} = \color{blue}{(p_i- y_i)}
  \text{ from the previous layer (from EqA1.1) } 
  \\ \\
   z^l = w^l a^{l-1}+b^l
    \text{ which makes }
    {\frac {\partial z^{l} }{\partial a^{l-1}} = w^l} \\
    \text{ and }
 a^{l-1} = \sigma (z^{l-1})     \text{ which makes }
\frac {\partial a^{l-1}}{\partial z^{l-1}} = \sigma \color{red}{'} (z^{l-1} )
\\ \\ \text{ Putting together we get the first part of Eq A2 }
\\\\
\color{blue}{\frac {\partial L}{\partial z^{l-1}}} =\color{blue}{(p_i- y_i)}.w^l.\sigma \color{red}{'} (z^{l-1} ) \rightarrow \text{EqA2.1 }
\\ \\
 z^{l-1} = w^{l-1} a^{l-2}+b^{l-1}
    \text{ which makes }
    \color{green}{\frac {\partial z^{l-1}}{\partial w^{l-1}}=a^{l-2}}
\\ \\
\frac {\partial L}{\partial w^{l-1}} 
=  \color{blue}{\frac {\partial L}{\partial z^{l-1}}}.
     \color{green}{\frac {\partial z^{l-1}}{\partial w^{l-1}}} = \color{blue}{(p_i- y_i)}.w^l.\sigma \color{red}{'} (z^{l-1} ).\color{green}{a^{l-2}}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

So far so good; Now here is the code snippet where I try to apply this. For the last layer it works. But for the inner layer it does not match weights. Which means I am somewhere wrong

---

Excerpt from https://github.com/alexcpn/cnn_in_python

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: "{0:0.2f}".format(x)})
    # Generate a random image
    image_size = 32 
    image_depth = 3
    image = np.random.rand(image_size, image_size)
    # to mimic RGB channel
    image = np.stack([image,image,image], axis=image_depth-1) # 0 to 2
    print("Image Shape=",image.shape)
    print("Image [0,0,:]=",image[0,1,2])

    # The class containing the convolution Logic
    testConv2D = cnn.Conv2D()

    # we will create leNet without the Pooling parts
    # (stride is always 1 for now)
    #  [32.32.3] *(5.5.3)*6  == [28.28.6] * (5.5.6)*1 = [24.24.1] *  (5.5.3)*16 = [20.20.16] * FC layer 
    
    print("-----------Forward Propagation------------------------")

    # For layer 1
    filter_size = 5  
    number_of_filters = 6
    # Initialize the weight's/filters of Layer1
    w1 = initializeWeights(number_of_filters,filter_size,image.shape[2])
    a1 = layerConvolutionActivation(image, filter_size,number_of_filters,w1)
    
     # For layer 2
    filter_size = 5  
    number_of_filters = 1
    # Initialize the weight's/filters of Layer1
    w2 =  initializeWeights(number_of_filters,filter_size,a1.shape[2])
    # Do convolution and activation
    a2 = layerConvolutionActivation(a1, filter_size,number_of_filters,w2)
    
    # For layer 3
    # Out=W−F+1 imagesize - filtersize + 1
    filter_size = 5  
    number_of_filters = 16
    # Initialize the weight's/filters of Layer1
    w3 =  initializeWeights(number_of_filters,filter_size,a2.shape[2])
    # Do convolution and activation
    a3 = layerConvolutionActivation(a2, filter_size,number_of_filters,w3)
    print("a3.shape=", a3.shape) # output_layer3 shape = (20, 20, 16)
        
    """ 
    Lets add the fully connected layer say 120 - we need the shape to be compatible - for that we are adding the
    the dimension of the above layer 
    """
    w4 =  np.random.rand(a3.shape[0],120,a3.shape[2]) 
    print("w4.shape =", w4.shape) # (20, 120, 16)
    # this time there is no convolution - rather we need to do a dot
    z4 = np.einsum('ijp,jkp->ik', a3, w4) # (20, 120)
    #output_layer4 = np.tensordot(output_layer3,weight_layer4,axes=2)
    print("z4.shape =", z4.shape)
    a4 = util.sigmoid(z4)
    print("a4.shape =", a4.shape)

    w5 =  np.random.rand(a4.shape[1],1) 
    print("w5.shape =", w5.shape) # (20, 120, 16)
    # this time there is no convolution - rather we need to do a dot
    z5 = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', a4, w5) # (20, 120)
    print("z5.shape =", z5.shape)
    a5 = util.sigmoid(z5)
    print("a5.shape =", a5.shape)
    a5_derv = util.derv_sigmoid(z5)
    print("a5_derv.shape =", a5_derv.shape)

    # final layer lets make it 10 classes
    w6 =  np.random.rand(a5.shape[0],10) 
    print("w6.shape =", w6.shape) # (20, 120, 16)
    # this time there is no convolution - rather we need to do a dot
    logits = np.einsum('ij,ik->jk', a5, w6).flatten() #  20,1*20,10 (1, 10) == Z_l
    z6 = logits
    print("z6.shape=", z6.shape) #(10,)
    #print("Final  Output  =", output_layer6)
    
    """
    Run Softmax
    """
    softmax_ouput =util.softmax(logits)
    a6 = softmax_ouput
    print("a6.shape =", a6.shape)
    print("Softmax Output  =", softmax_ouput)

     # Assume that the truth was class 1 , for this particular "image"
    target = np.array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0. ,0., 0. ,0 ,0., 0.])
     
    #Plug this into the cost function lets take the CrossEntropy Loss as this a classification
    # See this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEXPMQXoiLc  
    # Get index of the true class
    LcrossEntropyLoss = util.crossentropyloss(softmax_ouput,target)
    print("crossEntropyLoss  = ",LcrossEntropyLoss) # ex 3.75671634607845
    
    """
    Back-Propagate the Loss
    """
    print("-----------Back Propagation------------------------")

    lr = 1 # learning rate
    # https://alexcpn.github.io/html/NN/ml/7_backpropogation_full/
    D_S_by_z = util.derv_softmax_wrto_logits(softmax_ouput)
    D_L_by_z = util.derv_crossentropyloss_wrto_logits(softmax_ouput,target)

    # For the last layers  W= 6
    # EqA1 in https://alexcpn.github.io/html/NN/ml/7_backpropogation_full/
    activation_L =  softmax_ouput
    B0 = (activation_L -target)
    print("B0.shape =", B0.shape)
    D_L_by_w6 = B0 *a5
    print("BP: Last weight update - D_L_by_w6 shape==w6 shape",D_L_by_w6.shape,w6.shape)
    w6 = w6 - lr*D_L_by_w6
    

    print("-----------------------------------")
    # For the inner layers  W= 5
    # EqA2 in https://alexcpn.github.io/html/NN/ml/7_backpropogation_full/
    B1 = w6 * B0  
    B1 = B1 @ a5_derv
    print("B1 shape",B1.shape)
    D_L_by_w5 =   a4.T @ B1
    print("D_L_by_w5 shape",D_L_by_w5.shape)
    D_L_by_w5 = np.expand_dims(D_L_by_w5, axis=1)
    print("D_I_by_w5 shape",D_L_by_w5.shape)
    print("w5 shape", w5.shape)
    w5 = w5 - lr*D_L_by_w5
    print("w5 shape", w5.shape)
```

Output

```
cnn_1/cnn_py$ python3 main.py 
Image Shape= (32, 32, 3)
Image [0,0,:]= 0.5815285626863921
-----------Forward Propogation------------------------
Convolution Shape = (28, 28, 6)
Convolution Shape = (24, 24, 1)
Convolution Shape = (20, 20, 16)
a3.shape= (20, 20, 16)
w4.shape = (20, 120, 16)
z4.shape = (20, 120)
a4.shape = (20, 120)
w5.shape = (120, 1)
z5.shape = (20, 1)
a5.shape = (20, 1)
a5_derv.shape = (20, 1)
w6.shape = (20, 10)
z6.shape= (10,)
a6.shape = (10,)
Softmax Output  = [0.02 0.26 0.03 0.08 0.09 0.04 0.07 0.01 0.01 0.39]
crossEntropyLoss  =  4.091121759807155
-----------Back Propogation------------------------
1
B0.shape = (10,)
BP: Last weight update - D_L_by_w6 shape==w6 shape (20, 10) (20, 10)
-----------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/coding/cnn_1/cnn_py/main.py", line 172, in <module>
    B1 = B1 @ a5_derv
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 20 is different from 10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations were correct. I had done a mistake in the code ; there were some element wise operations and some `dot` product type operations. It is corrected now - code

```
   print("-----------Back Propogation------------------------")

    lr = 1 # learning rate
    # https://alexcpn.github.io/html/NN/ml/7_backpropogation_full/
    D_S_by_z = util.derv_softmax_wrto_logits(softmax_ouput)
    D_L_by_z = util.derv_crossentropyloss_wrto_logits(softmax_ouput,target)
    # For the last layers  W= 6
    # EqA1 in https://alexcpn.github.io/html/NN/ml/7_backpropogation_full/
    activation_L =  softmax_ouput
    DL_by_z6 = (activation_L -target)
    print("DL_by_z6.shape =", DL_by_z6.shape)
    D_L_by_w6 = DL_by_z6 *a5
    print("BP 6: Last weight update - D_L_by_w6 shape == w6 shape",D_L_by_w6.shape,w6.shape)
    w6 = w6 - lr*D_L_by_w6
    

    print("-----------------------------------")
    # For the inner layers  W= 5
    # EqA2 in https://alexcpn.github.io/html/NN/ml/7_backpropogation_full/
    a5_derv = util.derv_sigmoid(z5)
    #DL_by_z6 = np.expand_dims(DL_by_z6, axis=1)
    DL_by_z5 = DL_by_z6 @ w6.T  # @ is np.matmul (almost similar to np.dot -https://stackoverflow.com/a/34142617/429476 )
    DL_by_z5 = DL_by_z5 * a5_derv #  Hadamard product/element wise multiplication here (20, 1) * (20, 1)
    print("DL_by_z5 shape",DL_by_z5.shape) # (20, 1)
    D_L_by_w5 =   a4.T @ DL_by_z5
    print("D_L_by_w5 shape == w5 Shape",D_L_by_w5.shape,w5.shape)
   
    # Using gradient descent to update the weights
    print("BP 5: Last weight update")
    w5 = w5 - lr*D_L_by_w5
    print("w5 shape after update", w5.shape)
   
    print("-----------------------------------")
    # For the inner layers  W= 4
    a4_derv = util.derv_sigmoid(z4)
    DL_by_z4 = DL_by_z5 @ w5.T
    DL_by_z4 = DL_by_z4 * a4_derv #  Hadamard product/element wise multiplication here (20, 120) * (20, 120)
    print("DL_by_z4 shape",DL_by_z4.shape) # (20, 120)
    print("a3 shape",a3.shape)
    #D_L_by_w4 = a3.T @ DL_by_z4 #(20,20,16).T @ (20,120) ==> (16,20,120); we need 20,120,16; need np.Transpose or below
    D_L_by_w4=np.einsum('ijp,ik->ikp', a3, DL_by_z4) 
    print("D_L_by_w4 shape == w4 Shape",D_L_by_w4.shape,w4.shape)
    # Using gradient descent to update the weights
    print("BP 4: Last weight update")
    w4 = w4 - lr*D_L_by_w4
```

Output

````
-----------Back Propogation------------------------
1
DL_by_z6.shape = (10,)
BP 6: Last weight update - D_L_by_w6 shape == w6 shape (20, 10) (20, 10)
-----------------------------------
DL_by_z5 shape (20, 20)
D_L_by_w5 shape == w5 Shape (120, 20) (120, 1)
BP 5: Last weight update
w5 shape after update (120, 20)
-----------------------------------
DL_by_z4 shape (20, 120)
a3 shape (20, 20, 16)
D_L_by_w4 shape == w4 Shape (20, 120, 16) (20, 120, 16)
BP 4: Last weight update
```
````